# Element-wise mean of a list of pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a canonical way to compute the element-wise mean of a list of DataFrames with identical columns and indices?

The best way I can think of is

```py
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]  
reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y), dfs) / len(dfs)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `mean` per index values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'C':[7,8,9],
         'D':[1,3,5],

})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'C':[4,2,3],
         'D':[7,1,0],

})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
         'C':[9,4,2],
         'D':[1,7,1],

})

from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]  
df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y), dfs) / len(dfs)
print (df)
          C         D
0  6.666667  3.000000
1  4.666667  3.666667
2  4.666667  2.000000

df = pd.concat(dfs).mean(level=0)
print (df)
          C         D
0  6.666667  3.000000
1  4.666667  3.666667
2  4.666667  2.000000
```